# XHTML to XHTML with XSLT and its encodings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm learning XSLT, and as an exercise, I'm trying to get the top links of http://ptchan.org/fa/, namely  {al, az, fa, ga, li, tm}. To do so, I've created the following XSL Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Links</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//div[@class='navbar']/a">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="self::node()"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've also created a [dummy XML](http://pastebin.com/m48e3e78b) file representing just the nodes I want to get in the [regular file](http://pastebin.com/m4d786a08), which was generated via `curl http://ptchan.org/fa/ | tidy -utf8 -asxml`. Transforming, with `xsltproc`, works with the dummy file but not with the regular one. After some googling, I've found that the (1) DOCTYPE, and (2) `&nbsp;` on the source file are causing trouble, but even after removing them, the transformation doesn't occur.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong and on how to transform that file?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to mark whatever you put after (2) as code using `s.

Comment: Problems with entities would hint at `xsltproc` having trouble loading the DTD/entity definitions. Does running `xmllint --loaddtd` report any errors when run on the problematic input file? It might be that w3.org is blocking access to XHMTL DTDs from `xsltproc` (libxslt). Anyway, it's a good idea to have local copies of the needed DTDs, and set up XML catalogs so that those local copies are used. (For example, in Ubuntu installing package `w3c-dtd-xhtml` takes care of that for XHTML.)

Comment: And, to reduce problems with named entities (having to load the DTD to get their definitions), you might want to use the `-numeric` switch with `tidy`, to use numeric rather than named entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the namespace wasn't specified. There are no divs in the document, but xhtml:divs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `xsltproc`, the easiest way is just to use the the `-html` command line switch, and it should be able to process the "untidied" HTML input directly.